# Worst case of based on comparison sorting algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

> Explain by reference to the structure of a decision tree why any
>   sorting algorithm based on comparisons cannot in its worst case use
>   fewer comparison than a number proportional to nlog(n).

Any ideas how I can prove this?

Comment: This is a standard proof that appears in any book about algorithms. See, for example, [Wikipedia's page on comparison sorts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort#Number_of_comparisons_required_to_sort_a_list). If there's something specific you don't understand about the proof, please edit your question to address that.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your exercise problem for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion.  Also, we expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking, including consulting standard textbooks and Wikipedia.  If you haven't checked them, you probably haven't done enough research.

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/6562/755 (possible dup?)

Answer (score 3):

This is very, very classical. Here is the idea. You can describe a run of your algorithm as a decision tree. At each node there is a comparison operation performed by your algorithm, and the three children correspond to the three different answers. Every execution of your algorithm ends at a leaf. Since at the end the list is sorted, in particular we can tell what the original order of the list was. So we can annotate each leaf by a permutation on $n$ elements. Since there are $n!$ different permutations, there must be at least $n!$ leaves, so the tree must have height at least $\Omega(\log_3 n!) = \Omega(n\log n)$. This means that there is some computation path that will result in $\Omega(n\log n)$ comparisons.

If you're not happy with this argument, the web has many, many different versions of the same proof, which you can find using your web searching skills.